# How can I keep Wordpress website unavailable and private while developing online?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WP site on a localserver.
How can I upload a WP site on the web hosting provider while keeping the site private? How should I configure it to do this?

I would like to work on the WP site via the admin portal which requires login. Is the login protection on admin portal enough security when the site is online? Can we enable HTTPS on it?

If the domain registered is my-domain.com then my-domain.com/admin would be the admin page which is login protected? But my-domain.com will point to the actual WP site? Is this right? How can I make this website private? Is the option on WP to keep the site private enough?

Also how can I disable indexing so that site does not appear on search engines?

Comment: i would add simple Apache authorisation, easy to set up for a single person, and disable when done. (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) depend in on host, there control panel probably has a friendly interface for it.

Comment: There are also plenty of "under construction" plugins for WordPress that do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://your-domain.com/wp-admin/options-reading.php and check the "*Discourage search engines from indexing this site*" box under **Search Engine Visibility** title.

For private sites, you can use *privacy* or under *maintenance* plugins (do a Google search for them)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) that should work for you.

- Once enabled go to Settings -> Reading
- The 5th option down the page is "Site Visibility" tick the " Restrict site access to visitors who are logged in or allowed by IP address" option.
- **Optional steps**:
- You have a few other options:

  - Send them to the WordPress login screen
  - Redirect them to a specified web address
  - Show them a simple message
  - Show them a specific WordPress page I've created
  - Unrestricted IP addresses
- The "Unrestricted IP addresses" options allows you to enter your current or specific IP addresses so this plugin doesn't effect you.
- By default **only** logged in users will be able to see the website.
- Lastly click the "Save Changes" box to save your settings.